# Post exist photo on user timeline from Facebook API

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-timeline

Is it possible to post an existing photo on user timeline via `Facebook API`, without creating new album?

When I use

```php
$userdata_p = $facebook->api('/me/feed', 'post', array(
                               'message' => "some text",
                               'source' => '@' . realpath(path of image)
                             ));
```

With this code, I create an album and post the photo and the text on my timeline. But I don't want to create new album, instead I want to get the photo from existing album(photo) and post it on my timeline.

Answer (score 1):

You can post to the Graph API endpoint https://graph.facebook.com/ALBUM_ID/photos to add to an existing album.

See Facebook API documentation https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/